# Python - Saving and Recovering Image/Pictures/JPEG from PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

So, I'm trying to save an image into my PostgreSQL table in Python using psycopg2

INSERT Query (Insert.py)

```
#Folder/Picture is my path/ID is generated/IDnum is increment
picopen = open("Folder/Picture."+str(ID)+"."+str(IDnum)+".jpg", 'rb').read()
filename = ("Picture."+str(ID)+"."+str(IDnum)+".jpg")

#Sample file name is this Picture.1116578795.7.jpg

#upload_name is where I want the file name, upload_content is where I store the image
SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_upload (upload_name, upload_content) VALUES (%s, %s)"
data = (filename, psycopg2.Binary(picopen))
cur.execute(SQL, data)
conn.commit()
```

now to recover the saved Image I perform this query (recovery.py)

```
cur.execute("SELECT upload_content, upload_name from tbl_upload")
for row in cur:

    mypic = cur.fetchone()
    open('Folder/'+row[1], 'wb').write(str(mypic[0]))
```

now what happens is when I execute the recovery.py it does generate a ".jpg" file but I can't view or open it.

If it helps I'm doing it using Python 2.7 and Centos7.
for the sake of additional information, I get this on the image viewer when I open the generated file.

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x5c 0x78)
```

I also tried using other formats as well (.png, .bmp)

Comment: You are reading it binary with "rb" and while inserting into DB you are converting it to binary again. with "Binary()". May be that is causing problem. as I do not see any issue in reading

Comment: Thank you for responding lat long, I've tried just using "r" and "w" after I've read your comment, however the result is still the same.

Comment: what about using "r" for reading, "binary()" for writing into DB and then "wb" for recovering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I double checked my database type and apparently upload_content datatype is *text* its supposed to be *bytea* I thought I already had it set to bytea when I created my db. Problem solved.